# Vehicle routing multiple vehicles, multiple trips, finite vehicles in ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, vehicle-routing-problem

I am working on a problem where I have 30 vehicles who can all make at most 6 stops in a day. They have to service more than 500 shops.

I can get Network Analyst to do a Vehicle Routing Problem easily, but I can't figure out how to make the vehicles do multiple trips. The Network Analyst only lets me do one trip for each vehicle so that they only serve 180 shops.

How can I get ArcGIS to allow me to do multiple trips?

I am interested in distance of routes. I can measure this if I create enough vehicles to visit all the shops, but it is extremely tedious to create 75+ vehicles by hand ("Add Item") and will be impossible in my target case of more than 2000 shops.